# Prove the formula $(\exists x A(x) \to B) \to \forall y (A(y) \to B)$

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I need to prove the following formula
$$(\exists x A(x) \to B) \to \forall y (A(y) \to B)$$
Where $y\notin \mbox{free}(A)$ and $y\notin \mbox{free}(B)$

Axioms that I use.

**1.** $A \to (B \to A)$

**2.** $(A \to B) \to ( (A \to (B \to C)) \to (A \to C))$

**3.** $(\lnot B \to A) \to ((\lnot B \to \lnot A) \to B)$

**4.** $\forall x_i A(x_i) \to A(t)$ where $A$ is wf and $t$ is free for $x_i$ in $A$

**5.** $\forall (x_i) (A \to B) \to (A \to \forall x_i B)$ where $x_i$ is not bounded in $B$

Rules of inferences are Gen and Modus Ponens.

**Here's my try**.

$1. \vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x)$ (premise)

$2. \vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x) \to B $ (premise)

$3. \vdash B$ (1 and 2 m.p.)

**Lemma 0:** $ \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x) \vdash A(t)$

Suppose that

$1. \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x), \lnot A(t) \vdash \lnot A(t)$ (premise)

$2. \vdash \forall x \lnot A(x)$ (Gen 1.)

$3. \vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x)$ (premise)

Contradiction. So

$4. \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x) \vdash A(t)$

**End of Lemma 0**

$5. \vdash A(t)$ (1. and Lemma 0)

$6. \vdash (B \to (A(t) \to B))$ (A1)

$7. \vdash A(t) \to B$ (3 and 6 m.p.)

$8. \vdash \forall y (A(y) \to B$) (Gen 7.)

$9. \vdash (\lnot \forall x \lnot A(x) \to B) \to \forall y (A(y) \to B$) (Deduction theorem)

But I think I left an error **in** the step 7. Everything below that is true, only if $\lnot \forall x \lnot A(x)$ is true.

Maybe there's an easier way?

P.S:  $\exists$ is an abbreviation for: $\lnot \forall \lnot$ (Thanks to @MauroALLEGRANZA)

Comment: It seems correct to me: the application of DT is right, because in the derivation Gen is used on the var $x$ that is not *free* in the premises.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks for the feedback. I think my mistake is **in** the step 7, but not after it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your proof system is that of Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72), CRC Press (6th ed 2015); see page 72 for the *Deduction Th*.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 8 and 9 are fine ... but your Lemma is not.  What you need to show is $A(t) \vdash \neg \forall x \neg A(x)$, so that together with $\neg \forall x \neg A(x) \rightarrow B$ you can get $A(t) \rightarrow B$ and then apply 8 and 9.

Also, while I don't know the exact notation of your system, I find the way you introduce premises suspect. For example, you write:

> $1. \vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x)$ (premise)

Given the $\vdash$, that looks like a theorem, not a premise. I would suspect that something like:

> $1. \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x) \vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x)$ (premise)

or simply

> $1. \lnot \forall x \lnot A(x) $ (premise)

would be called for.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. Maybe I messed the syntax. I should have put premises in left hand side. So it will be obvious. Let me try your suggestion.