# Show that $(\exists v_0 \varphi \to \psi) \vdash \forall v_0 (\varphi \to \psi)$

Tags: predicate-logic

The proposition in the title should be proven with the following axioms:

1. Any $L$-Tautologies
2. $\forall$-Axiom $(\forall v_i \varphi \to \varphi \frac{\tau}{v_i})$ $v_i$ is free for $\tau$ in $\varphi$

3. Modus Ponens
4. $\forall$-Introduction if $T \vdash \varphi$ then $T \vdash \forall v_i \varphi $

I am looking for a simple hint,  because I have been spinning my wheels for way too long with this problem. If axioms are unclear, I apologize and I will try to clarify it.

Comment: You cannot prove this without having some axioms which govern the existential quantifier! You need the analogue of what you call the $\forall$-Axiom and $\forall$-Introduction for the existential quantifier.

Once you have that, work backwards. You want to prove a universally quantified sentence. Which rule allows you to do that?

Comment: We probably need to assume that $v_0$ is not free in $\psi$, right?

Comment: What if we assume that we can simply rewrite $\exists v_0 \varphi$ as $\lnot \forall v_0 \lnot \varphi$?

Comment: The statement to prove is equivalent to a *logical axiom* in a book I have and proving it should be similar to proving that axiom.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570349/prove-the-formula-exists-x-ax-to-b-to-forall-y-ay-to-b)